# date_default_timezone_get() returns the wrong timezone

Tags: 7

I have several Drupal 7 sites using the same installation in the same server. Two of those sites are returning "Europe/London" when running `date_default_timezone_get()`. This timezone is different from the one returned by `drupal_get_user_timezone()` or `variable_get('date_default_timezone')`, which (correctly) return "America/Denver". For the rest of the sites the returned timezone is the same for all three functions.

The fact that I get a different timezone with the php function is creating issues for those two sites; for example, token replacements of date field are returning London time, not the site timezone's time.

What may be causing this discrepancy? Is there any way to correct that? I tried including the line `date.timezone = "America/Denver"` in `php.ini` without success.

I'm running php5.6 on Apache 2.4.36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. I am using the module `print` with the external   library `mPDF` (version 6.0). `mPDF.php` was changing my default timezone to "Europe/London" in line 80 (this bug has been reported in this version of mPDF). Apparently this line was running after `drupal_session_initialize()` in `session.inc`, which sets the default timezone for the session to match the site's selected timezone.

What's strange is that mPDF was only affecting 2 of my sites. Apparently the session initialization in the other sites was running after the mPDF command? I commented out those lines and all the timezones now match.